# Oracle Stored Procedure "Encountered the symbol... " error

Tags: database, oracle, symbols, procedure

After a looong research i have decided i have no idea what causes the following problem! I want to create a stored procedure that will increase the value of a column if that satisfied a statement.I can run the procedure as a anonymous block but i cant run it as a stored procedure!

Here is the stored procedure code:

```
1 create or replace
2 Procedure RaiseSalary
3 Is
4 Salary number;
5 Cursor RaiseCursor
6 Is
7 Select Salary_A From Person Where Salary_A<400 for update of Salary_A;
8 Begin 
9 Open RaiseCursor;
10    Loop
11 Fetch RaiseCursor Into Salary;
12    Exit When RaiseCursor%Notfound;
13 Update Person Set Salary_A=(Salary + 200) Where Current Of RaiseCursor;
14    End Loop;
15 Close RaiseCursor;
16 Commit;
17 End;
```

I am getting an error at line 3 that says "Encountered the symbol "SALARY" when expecting one of the following:...." and i am getting the same error at line 5 at the "s" letter of the word Cursor ,but at this time it says ";" instead of "Salary". The compiler log shows "insufficient privileges" but i can't find a reasonable explanation for this. 
I have tried to run the code as an anonymous block like this:

```
 Declare
 Salary number;
 Cursor RaiseCursor
 Is
  Select Salary_A From Person Where Salary_A<400 for update of Salary_A;
  Begin
  Open RaiseCursor;
    Loop
  Fetch RaiseCursorInto Salary ;
    Exit When RaiseCursor%Notfound;
  Update Person Set Salary_A =(Salary + 200) Where Current Of RaiseCursor;
    End Loop;
  Close RaiseCursor;
  Commit;
  End;
  .
  run;
```

And works great!!!I am sure that i have the privileges to write stored procedures because i have created some successfully!
Am i doing something so wrong? I can't figure out what causes the problem, if you have any suggestions i would really appreciate that:)

EDIT: For some reason my procedure got wrong Schema that's why i had that problem! I only dropped the Procedure and create it again and it fixed!!!!
Thanks for your time anyway!

Comment: From the line numbers it looks like you're compiling your procedure in SQL*Plus. Can you type `show error` after this and post all the output. If the problem is permissions it should give a clue as to which you're missing.

Comment: First of all thanks for your time! Now, i don't use SQL*Plus i have written the line numbers manually so i could point to them easily.I use Sql Developer btw.

Comment: Please include the full error messages.

Comment: I have included all the error messages i got, insufficient privileges and all that stuff.Except that, my error got solved as i describe at the edit of my post:)

Answer (score 6):

Let me just point out this would be vastly more efficient if you did it as:

```
UPDATE Person Set Salary_A=(Salary_A + 200)
 Where Salary_A<400
```

No cursor, no looping. It would also be a lot simpler.